# Using period to access object's property but undefined

Tags: javascript

I am doing the codecademy's javascript tutorial and encountering the problem as following:

```
var friends = {};
friends.bill = {
  firstName: "Bill",
  lastName: "Gates",
  number: "(206) 555-5555",
  address: ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']
};
friends.steve = {
  firstName: "Steve",
  lastName: "Jobs",
  number: "(408) 555-5555",
  address: ['1 Infinite Loop','Cupertino','CA','95014']
};
var list = function(obj){
    for(var prop in obj){
        console.log(prop);
    }
};
var search = function(name) {
  for(var prop in friends){ 
        console.log(prop);
        console.log(friends.prop);//friends[prop] will print out 

  }


};
list(friends);
search("Steve");
```

the console.log(friends.prop) will print out undefined but if I changed it to

friends[prop],  it will print out the bill and steve object information.

I see the w3c tutorial say that two of the access method is right and I cannot figure out

what is the problem?

Thx in advance.

Comment: You'll need to use the bracket notation method when using variables with objects like that, so just use `friends[prop]` as `friends.prop` will never work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array notation (`[prop]`) is providing an additional level of indirection, a type of reflection.

So, `friends.bill` and `friends["bill"]` would be identical.  But, if you want to do something like `var prop = 'bill'`, then the only way to use this is as `friends[prop]`.

If you try `friends.prop`, you're literally asking for it to look for a friend named "prop".